# Captchas to force user interaction?

Tags: user-interface, captcha

I'm currently working on a program that has many of those "the user SHOULD read it but he'll click OK like a stupid monkey" dialogs... So I was thinking of adding something like a captcha in order to avoid click-without thinking...

My ideas were:

- Randomly change buttons
- Randomly position buttons somewhere on the form
- The user must click on a randomly colored word within the text he should read
- add captcha
- add captcha that includes the message for the user

Has anybody made any experience with such a situation. What would you suggest to do?

Comment: What falls under "things the user SHOULD read"?

MSN

Comment: I guess there is a typo in the tags, please correct it. You should also add "user-interface" tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you asked for opinions and here goes mine, but I don't think this is what you would like to hear...

Users like programs that they can depend on. They don't like when things change and they don't like to do extra work.

Randomly change buttons and Randomly position buttons somewhere on the form will only make them either press the wrong button or become annoyed with your application, because as you say, they don't read the text, and if you think about it, neither do we. As an example think of an Ok/Cancel dialog, you allways expect the ok button to be on the left, and most times i press it without reading it. It Will happen exactly the same with your users.

- The user must click on a randomly colored word within the text he should read
- add captcha
- add captcha that includes the message for the user

With these 3 option you will add extra work to your application, your users will curse you for that. Just think of something that you would have to do 10x per day, let's say check in your code to source safe. How would you feel if your boss told you that from now on you will have to fill a captcha for each file you try to check in?

I think it's our jobs to make the lives of the people that use our software easier. If they must read some kind of text and they don't want to, there is absolutely no way you can make them do it.

You can´t make people work right, all you can do is provide them with the best possible tools and hope that they are professional enough to do their jobs.

So basically all i'm saying is, do your best to ease their work. If this is really important than you(or whoever is in charge) should talk to them and EXPLAIN WHY this is important.

You would be surprised on how people commit to things they understand.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you don't; and that, unless you know better, you emulate respectable well-known, well-tested UIs like <*big online retailer's*> or <*online banking site*>.

Answer (score 3):

Redesign your application so that it does not use message boxes.

Answer (score 3):

Playing games with the user in order to get them to read messages is doomed. Users will focus mental resources on completing your game, rather than understanding the message. Your users may be *less* likely to actually understand the important part of the message if you have things like moved buttons, relabeling, scavenger hunts, captchas, or delays. They’ll focus on the instructions for the game, not on the real issue. Errors are likely to increase.

Users’ refusal to read message boxes is due to users wanting to get things done quickly rather than take the time to read stuff, and it is also due to message boxes being overused and misused so badly in so many apps. Including silly games in message boxes will just make users resent them all the more, compounding the problem.

Here’s what you can do:

Rule 1. Don’t use messages boxes. They should only appear for exceptional circumstances. An app should not have “many” message boxes. It should not be necessary to read a whole lot of documentation each time the user uses an app. If *normal* use of your app results in a message box, then your UI is wrong. Find another way.

- Instead of verification messages, show clearly in the main window what has happened and provide a clear way to Undo it.
- Use auto-correction, pictured/masked fields, and disabling rather than error messages.
- Use good defaults and automation to avoid messages. For example, rather than showing an error message saying the user can’t upload because they’re not connected to the server, simply reconnect automatically.
- Break commands along options. Rather that a message box to ask if the user wants paste with or without format, provide two different commands in the menu.
- Don’t have information messages spontaneously popping up telling the user everything worked fine (e.g., “Preferences Saved!”)
- Don’t have pop-ups providing helpful hints or documentation. Provide a tutorial or balloon help if you can’t make your UI self-documenting.
- Don’t have nagging “upgrade me” messages.
- Consider providing message text in the main window rather than in a separate message box (e.g., “Page may not look or act right because ActiveX is off for security.”). Pop-ups from web surfing have conditioned users to automatically dismiss anything that pops up as irrelevant.

Rule 2. If you *have* to use a message:

- Make the text as brief as possible to get the key information across. More text is not equivalent to more helpful. Use “No match to [filemask] in [path].” Don’t use “Nonfatal Error 307: Search action aborted. [Appname] is unable to complete your string search for the regular expression you provided because the file mask you gave, namely [filemask], does not result in any matching files in the directory that you specified (which was [path]). Please check your filemask or path selection and again re-enter it or them in the Files to Search dialog box. Click the OK button below on this message box to return to the Files to Search dialog box. Click the Cancel Button on the Files to Search dialog when you get there to cancel your search for strings.” If there are some users who will need more explanation than can be achieved in a brief message, provide a Help button or a “How do I…” link in the message box.
- Use plain language and no jargon in the message. That includes “innocent” words like “dialog,” “database,” and “toner.” Do not take raw exception text and throw it in a error message. Do not include any error numbers or dumps; log these instead. Purge your app of any debugging message boxes left by developers. Better to simply let the app disappear on a fatal error than to put up a message full of jargon and *then* the app disappears.
- Label the buttons of a message box with what the action does, not “OK.” At the very least, the users have to focus on the activating button to dismiss a message box. If that button is labeled something like “Delete” or “Install,” it should give them pause. You should never have to explain in your message text what each button does. BTW, such labeling is a GUI standard on most platforms.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion, live with it or redesign your dialogs/interface.  Do **not** add randomness to dialogs or otherwise treat the user like an idiot, even though you may think most are :-).

I just recently read a Joel on Software article, [Designing for People Who Have Better Things To Do With Their Lives](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000062.html).  It makes the point that most people won't read **anything** and discusses ways to work around that or at least not make it worse.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with a timer which waits for the "supposed reading time" before enabling the submit button. You can even calculate the supposed reading time from the number of words.

I think that subtle ways to force the user to read your text (like moving around buttons or asking them to read a captcha) can make them feel like stupid monkeys.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a choice question based on what the user should read.

Comment: Yes, if you want users to hate the application :-)

Comment: LOL Sometimes I forget I am a user too ;)